# path to /opt/python3.5.0/bin for the usage of python3

Tags: python, path

I installed python3.5.0 in /opt/python3.5.0/bin/, but I couldn't use it beyond this bin folder. I know this is a path issue. Could somebody point out the correct procedure to make python3 show up in the system for use? The operating system is CentOS6.6

Comment: On which operating system is this?

Answer (score 0):

The os needs to know where your python executable is.

Try running it from somewhere else

```
  cd 
  /opt/python3.5.0/bin/python -V
```

If that works the your Python3 installation in opt is ok and you just need to let your shell (probably bash) know where the python binary is by changing your PATH environment variable.

```
export PATH=/opt/python3.5.0/bin/:$PATH
```

Run that line on the bash terminal and try running python again with no path like this:

```
python -V
```

If that works put the export PATH=/opt/python3.5.0/bin/:$PATH line  in your .bashrc or .bash_profile so it will work in the console in future.

Failing all that take a look at setting the PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH environment variables.

Also a better approach might be to install python3 using your package manager.  The python3 executable should give you a version of Python-3 if you have one installed.  Though you might get a different version of Python3 than 3.5 that way.